# Can we make File Explorer accept PowerShell variables?

Tags: powershell, windows-explorer, environment-variables

More and more, PowerShell is the de facto standard scripting language for Windows, and yet, in File Explorer, we are still stuck using DOS variables.

e.g., you can type the following into the address bar of File Explorer:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

But you *cannot* use the following in the File Explorer address bar:

```
$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop
```

It's long overdue that we should be able to utilise PowerShell variables like the above, and it's *natural* to use this syntax as normal technical users use PowerShell all day long, but almost never use Command Prompt, so it's awkward to have to copy/paste a PowerShell formatted path from VS Code and then have to muck about changing it to DOS when going to File Explorer.

Are there any workarounds? Possibly a registry hack that updates File Explorer to accept PowerShell variable formats? Or some other solution? I know one workaround could be to do `Start $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop`, but it's not really useful as I'm normally in VS Code when I'm looking at these paths.

Comment: Not possible. But have you looked at the shell:xxx locations? They are buildin explorer, such as `shell:startup`, `shell:common desktop`, `shell:desktop`, `shell:profile` etc... see also: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/list-of-windows-11-shell-commands-for-shell-folder-shortcuts.1080/ you could use `shell:profile\desktop` if you wanted...

Comment: Also, you can launch an explorer window from powershell, so you can technically do what you want from powershell.

Comment: @LPChip, see OP, I know that's possible, but mostly I'm in VS Code when I'm doing this (yes, there is a terminal built in, but it's not the most convenient when we could do this with Command Prompt `%var%` but not `$env:var`. Yes, `shell:` syntax is very useful, but it's sort of clunky that we are tied to yesterdays syntax (`%var%`) in the modern world... I wasn't aware of doing `shell:profile\desktop` that's good to know also. Even if it *might* not be possible, it should be possible. Microsoft do great stuff, but they are a bit lazy about consolidating changes (like the move to PowerShell).

Comment: You cannot use variables from other tools if you are not already running the tool. The Windows OS does not run on PS by default, that is the ```cmd.exe``` role, hence the reason Explorer works as it does since it ```cmd.exe``` is the OS's shell, not PS.  To do what you are after, ***MS would have to completely rewrite how Explorer works***, and other is no financial/operations reason for the to do so. Many aspects of the OS use PS, but it is launching that as needed. There are lots of stuff MS should change, for example making VSC the default vs Notepad. Just say'in... ***;-}***

Comment: PowerShell is dependent on cmd.exe, and .Net/.Net Core to be able to run. It's not its own standalone shell. MS would have to rewrite the core OS to dump cmd.exe for PS so that boot-up is always PS, Imagine how many cmd.exe fans will revolt if that happened; as noted by the number that keeps trying to completely disable/remove PS, due to their perceived threat regarding it.

Comment: I'm fine with the underlying elements of cmd.exe, that's not a problem at all (I'm completely ok if cmd.exe stays around forever; it causes no issues). What I'm pointing out is that there should be a way to extend the rest of the OS to take advantage of the developments made to the shell instead of keeping everything bound back to the year 1995 where DOS environment variables work, but PowerShell syntax does not. I'm not arguing for cmd.exe to be thrown out; instead, I'm just looking for a way that powershell syntax can be used **in addition to** the cmd.exe syntax.

Comment: You can use PowerShell variables within PowerShell to have File Explorer open a folder no problem e.g. `Explorer.exe "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Test4321"`... This works as expected having Windows File Explorer open the folder passing it the PowerShell environmental variable accordingly. PowerShell syntax environmental variables are able to work with Explorer.exe within PowerShell just fine. If you are using batch, then use cmd syntax accordingly like from `run` or `cmd` or File Explorer address bar.

Comment: @Vomit IT, sure, but it's cludge. We can seamlessly use `%USERPROFILE%` in File Explorer itself, but cannot seamlessly use `$HOME` or `$Env:USERPROFILE` in File Explorer. It would be trivial for Microsoft to build PowerShell support into File Explorer, and give us both options.

Comment: Far from perfect, but you could luse the following as a context menu item for `HKCR\Directory\Background\Shell` and `HKCR\Desktop\Background\Shell`: `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile  -Command "&{Invoke-Expression ('explorer {0}' -f (Read-Host PSPath) ) }"`. You get the **PowerShell** console in your face, but it would let you copy from VSCode, right-click in Exploer or on the Desktop, click, Ctrl+V,<Enter> to open a new Explorer window to the folder.